# Make HTTP request with cherrypy

Tags: python, httprequest, cherrypy

I've searched for a long time but I can't find any documentation on how to create an HTTP request with cherrypy.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):

    json = http_request("http://somesite/")

    processed = process_json(json)

    tmpl = env.get_template("template.html")
    return tmpl.render(data=processed)
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: have a look at the python `requests` library. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/.

Comment: Cherrypy is for serving requests not for creating them. You should use urllib or requests to send HTTP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want urllib if you're talking about python 3.

```
import urllib.request

@cherrypy.tools.json_in() 
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):    
    httpreq = urllib.request.Request(url="http://somesite/")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(httpreq)
    jsonobject = response.read()
```

Let me know if you need another version of python.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using 2.7 so is there anything similar?